# Number of itersection points between two monotonously decreasing functions

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two **different** functions, where:

- $f(x)$ is **infinitely differentiable** for every $x$
- $g(x)$ is **infinitely differentiable** for every $x$
- $f'(x)$ is negative for every $x$ (i.e., $f(x)$ is monotonously decreasing)
- $g'(x)$ is negative for every $x$ (i.e., $g(x)$ is monotonously decreasing)

I am suspecting that the possible number of intersection points for any such pair of functions is:

- $0$
- $1$
- $2$
- $\infty$ (if the functions "merge" at some point; not even sure if that's possible)

How can we prove or refute this?

I emphasized **infinitely differentiable** in order to avoid function definitions such as:
$
 f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
  \dots & \text{$ x \leq K$}\\
  \dots & \text{$ x \geq K$}\\
 \end{cases}
$

Thanks

Comment: The assumptions on $f'$ and $g'$ are not quite useful for your question, because for any $f$ and $g$, there exists $h$, such that $h'> f'$ and $h'>g'$. For example, $h$ can be chosen as $h(x)=\int_0^x((f'(t))^2+(g'(t))^2)dt+x$. Then you can replace $f$ by $f-h$ and replace $g$ by $g-h$.

Answer (score 4):

The property you are looking for isn't going to work as stated. By choosing a suitable value of $c$ near $-2$, the functions $f(x)=\sin x-2x$ and $g(x)=cx$ can be made to intersect $n$ times for any integer $n$, or $\infty$ times for $c=2$, even though they both have strictly negative derivatives.

Even if you demand that *all* derivatives are negative, you still can't limit the number of intersection points. Consider the function $h(x)=p(2^x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k2^{kx}$, where $p(t)$ is a polynomial. There is a unique polynomial of degree $n$ passing through any $n+1$ points; choose $p(t)$ such that $p(0)=1$ and $p(2^x)=0$ for $x\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then $h(x)$ is a linear combination of exponentials that has roots at $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Now let $f(x)$ be the sum of all positive terms and $g(x)$ be the sum of all negative terms in $h(x)$. Then $f(x)+g(x)=h(x)$, and $f(x)$ has entirely positive derivatives, and $g(x)$ has entirely negative derivatives. (Note that neither $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is zero, because $h$ has a root and $f,g$ don't.) Thus $-f$ and $g$ are functions with all negative derivatives, crossing at $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

As an example for $n=4$:

$$f(x)=1+\frac{35}{32}2^{2x}+\frac1{64}2^{4x};\qquad g(x)=-\frac{15}82^x-\frac{15}{64}2^{3x}$$

A challenge to readers: can you generalize this construction to a countably infinite number of intersection points?

---

But your original idea is not too far off the mark; there *is* a property of the sort you are looking for, namely convexity. A function with a positive second derivative is convex, and convex functions can intersect a line at most twice. (If you allow the derivative to be zero, it may coincide with the line on an interval, hence your "$\infty$ intersections" case.) Thus, a revised theorem statement:

> If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are twice-differentiable functions such that $f''(x)<g''(x)$ for all $x$, then $f$ intersects $g$ at most twice.

Comment: Thank you Mario Carneiro. The original motivation for my question stems from a different issue, while trying to prove or refute that the two functions $f(x)=\log_5(0.7-2^x)$ and $g(x)=\log_2(0.7-5^x)$ intersect only at one point, namely $(-1,-1)$. So I might publish that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = -x^3 - x$ and let $f(x) = -2x$. Both have a negative first derivative, but they intersect at three points.

Edit: to follow up on Mario Carneiro's comment below: try to convince yourself that for any $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists a smooth function $h_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that 1) $h_n'(x) \le 1$ for all $x$, and 2) $h_n$ has exactly $n$ zeroes. Then $f(x) = -2x$ and $g(x) = -2x + h_n(x)$ both have derivatives less than or equal to $-1$ but intersect at $n$ points.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to think how to distinguish those cases where both functions "truly decrease". Your answer provides a good counterexample. $x^3$ has a curve point, where the derivative becomes $0$. But $-x^3-x$ doesn't appear to "have that problem". Perhaps I should state that **all** derivatives are negative for every $x$, until a certain point when they become $0$ for every $x$.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't think you are going to get the property you're looking for, if the conditions on $f$ and $g$ are the same; you just do minor variations about one or the other (my own counterexample would have been $\sin x-2x$ and $cx$ as $c\to-2$, which intersect as many times as you like).

Comment: That will be a tough distinction to make.The solutions of $g(x) = f(x)$ are exactly the solutions of $g(x) + h(x) = f(x) + h(x)$ for any smooth function $h$.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: How can the derivative of $sin x$ be negative for every $x$?

Comment: @barakmanos It's not; this is a counterexample to the original question.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: The original question states that the derivative is negative for every $x$.

Comment: @barakmanos The derivative of $\sin x-2x$ is $\cos x-2$, which is at most $-1$. (My earlier denial was to all derivatives being negative.)

Comment: @barakmanos Regarding functions with all negative derivatives that intersect at **three** points, the function $h(x)=\frac15+\frac x{30}-e^x+e^{2x}$ has three zeros, so the functions $f(x)=-e^x$ and $g(x)=-\frac15-\frac x{30}-e^{2x}$ have all derivatives strictly negative, and yet still cross at three points.